# Is this way of making a Dropdown using Angular bad practice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, ecmascript-6

I'm failry new to Angular and I've recently tried to create my first dropdown using it and it works really well. But since it's causing quite many comparisons, I am wondering if this way of doing it is bad practice.

I have one template which looks like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="dropdown-wrapper" *ngFor="let location of locations;">
        <div class="dropdown-title" (click)="showDropItems(location)">{{ location }}</div>
        
        <div *ngFor="let bot of bots;">
            <div *ngIf="bot.location === location && showItems(location)" class="dropdown-item">
                {{bot.id}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In here, I first only render unique locations, which are stored in the locations set defined in the class component. Onclick I then toggle the value of a locationsShow Map, so in the div underneath I can compare those values with the location value of the current bot being looped. This way the dropdown-items(bots) are shown under the right location and are only visible if the matching location got clicked. The data of the bots is fetched from a JSON file.

The class file looks as follows:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private botService: BotService) { }

  public bots: Array<Bot> = [];
  public locations = new Set();
  public locationsShow = new Map<string, boolean>();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllBots();
  }

  showItems(location: any)
  {
    return this.locationsShow.get(location);
  }

  showDropItems(location: any)
  {
    this.locationsShow.set(location, !this.locationsShow.get(location))
  }

  getAllBots() {
    this.botService.getAllBots()
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.bots = response;
        console.log(response);
        this.bots.forEach((bot, i) =>{
          this.locations.add(bot.location);
          this.locationsShow.set(bot.location, false);
        })
      }

      )
  }
```

Since the functions are called quite often and therefor are causing many comparisons when iterating through the for-loop, I'm wondering if this is bad practice or if it's fine. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's definitely a bad practice is not handling your subscriptions! Be sure to save result of your subscription call (this.subscription = this.obs$.subscribe()..) in a variable and unsubscribing from it in OnDestroy -> this.subscription.unsubscribe(). This way you won't produce memory leaks whenever component is destroyed and recreated

Comment: There's a great resource explaining your doubt, but I think you're already aware of your problem. https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496 For such a low-cost check I wouldn't worry too much. . You may want to try out OnPush strategy if you're concerned with performance

Comment: @michal.materowski You are absolutely right and thanks for the resource!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
*ngIf="bot.location === location && showItems(location)"
```

Is causing the `showItems(location)` function to be called once per item, for every Change Detection cycle (which might happen multiple times in a single second, unless you set your component as OnPush).
When you do this kind of bindings, object dictionaries are your friends:

TS:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private botService: BotService) { }

  public bots: Array<Bot> = [];
  public locations = new Set();
  public locationsShow: {[index: string]: boolean} = {};

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllBots();
  }

  showDropItems(location: any)
  {
    this.locationsShow[location] = !this.locationsShow[location];
  }

  getAllBots() {
    this.botService.getAllBots()
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.bots = response;
        console.log(response);
        this.bots.forEach((bot, i) =>{
          this.locations.add(bot.location);
          this.locationsShow[bot.location] = false;
        })
      }

      )
  }
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="dropdown-wrapper" *ngFor="let location of locations;">
        <div class="dropdown-title" (click)="showDropItems(location)">{{ location }}</div>
        
        <div *ngFor="let bot of bots;">
            <div *ngIf="bot.location === location && locationsShow[location]" class="dropdown-item">
                {{bot.id}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Also, you should rename `showDropItems` to `toggleDropItems` and handle your `.subscribe` by unsubscribing in the onDestroy

Comment: Feel free to upvote it and mark it as resolving if it actually helps you to solve the issue :) 


I've been working with Angular since version 2 and since i started binding to dictionaries in every kind-of-dynamic performance critical scenario i could actually enjoy life

Comment: That's a pretty handy pattern to cache such computations in a dictionary, will definitely use that +1!